# How to get url image page the right way?

Tags: theme-development, get-posts, theme-customizer

I’m developing my own top-down template, loading all pages in the main page.
My problem is that in the places of images appears only the last to be charged. For example, if I have three pages, each page with a different image, the image that will appear is always the image of the last page.

I do not know what the problem is, I’ve seen problems cache, problems with the same variable names and can not solve it.

You can see how can i do that:

```
<section id="about">
  <?php
    $about = get_page_by_title( 'About' );
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($about);
    $abouturl = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($thumb_id);
  ?>
  <span><?php echo $about->post_title ?></span>
  <img src="<?php echo $abouturl ?>"/>
</section>
<section id="news">
  <ul>
    <?php
    $posts = get_posts(['cat' => get_cat_ID('News'), 'limit' => 3, 'order' => 'DESC']);
    foreach($posts as $post){
      setup_postdata($post);
      $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post, 'news-image');
      $url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($thumb_id, '300, 300');
    ?>
    <li data-link="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(array(300, 150)); ?>"/>
      <span>
        <?php echo the_title(); ?>
      </span>
    </li>
    <?php
    wp_reset_postdata();
     }?>
  </ul>
</section>
<section id="contacts">
 <?php
    $contacts = get_page_by_title( 'Contacts' );
    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($contacts);
    $contactsurl = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($thumb_id);
  ?>
  <span><?php echo $contacts->post_title ?></span>
  <img src="<?php echo $contactsurl ?>"/>
</section>
```

How can i solve that?
If you need any more information please ask.

Thank’s

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing it is because you are using

```
echo the_post_thumbnail_url(array(300, 150));
```

instead of

```
the_post_thumbnail_url(array(300, 150));
```

`the_post_thumbnail_url` echos the output for you.

Another observation, the `the_post_thumbnail_url` uses the post data that is setup using `setup_postdata`, so there is no need for these two lines:

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post, 'news-image');
$url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url($thumb_id, '300, 300');
```

Comment: doesn't work yet! And if I take the last url others are also blank. On page load to see the all images loaded but then just assume the last.

Comment: Do you mind updating your code example with all code.